# C: how to apply a sequence of variables to a function?

Tags: c, apply

In C, is there a way to call a function with arguments stored in some array? I'm a C newbie, I'm not even sure if this is right but e.g.:

```
void f0(int a) { ... };
void f1(int a, int b) { ... };
void f2(int a, int b, int c) { ... };

int array[5][2][?] = [
    [&f0, [5]],
    [&f1, [-23, 5]],
    [&f2, [0, 1, 2]],
    [&f2, [1235, 111, 4234]],
    [&f0, [22]]
];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    APPLY?(array[i][0], array[i][1])
}
```

PS: What kind of structure should I use when the array's items vary in length?

In Python, this would be:

```
def f0(a): ...
def f1(a, b): ...
def f2(a, b, c): ...

array = [
    (f0, (5,)),
    (f1, (-23, 5)),
    (f2, (0, 1, 2)),
    (f2, (1235, 111, 4234)),
    (f0, (22,))
]

for f, args in array:
    apply(f, args)
```

Comment: There might be a simpler way to accomplish your goal, what are you trying to do? and what are your limitations with data etc?

Comment: This can probably be done with `varargs`, which I will make no attempt to explain.

Comment: You could use a struct.

here's some info on structs (a simple object) http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-structure.aspx

struct shape{
   int numberOfPoints;
   int points[4];
   char shapeType[10];
}

You could store the shape type in the shapeType string, and the points in the point array, and pass each index to a function to plot the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possibly to have variable arity functions in C, but the mechanism is clunky and has certain restrictions, namely, there must be at least one fixed parameter, and you need to be able to tell from the fixed parameters or from the variable parameters themselves where the end of the variable list is.

A more typical solution, one that plays to C's strengths rather than its weaknesses, is something like this example. (*Updated with function pointers*.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(int, int *);
void f2(int, int *);

struct BoxOfInts {
    void (*f)(int,int *);
    int howMany;
    int theNumbers[4];
} intMachine[] = {
    {f1, 1,  { 5,  }},
    {f2, 2,  { -23, 5  }},
    {f1, 3,  { 0, 1, 2  }},
    {f2, 3,  { 1235, 111, 4234  }},
    {f1, 1,  { 22,  }},
    { 0 }
};

void dispatch(void)
{
    for(struct BoxOfInts *p = intMachine; p->f; ++p)
        (*p->f)(p->howMany, p->theNumbers);
}

void f1(int howMany, int *p)
{
    while (howMany-- > 0) {
        int t = *p++;
        printf("f1 %d %d\n", howMany, t);
    }
}

void f2(int howMany, int *p)
{
    while (howMany-- > 0) {
        int t = *p++;
        printf("f2 %d %d\n", howMany, t);
    }
}

int main()
{
  dispatch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the {} at the top? Variable length arrays?
Also, I wanted to call various f-s (f0, f1, f2), how do I add them to the array and call the appropriate one in dispatch?

Comment: Note also that stdarg.h doesn't allow for building arbitrary argument arrays, only copying ones that already exist.  You'd still have to do the marshalling in assembly, or via a huge array of helper functions a-la Glib/Gtk.

Comment: The `{}` syntax defines an *initializer-list`, these sometimes-optional groups tell the compiler when a list for a given aggregate element is done. I didn't realize you wanted different functions for reasons other than arity. I've put them in the revised example.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no.

A better way to do this in C would be to define your functions to all have the same signature, like:

```
void f0(int size, int elements[])
```

and then pass arrays of the appropriate size to your functions.

```
// this is a function pointer
void (*x)(int, int[]); 
...
// set x to point at f0
x = f0;
// call x (ie: f0) with 1 element from position 5 of array
x(1, &(array[5]));
```

Comment: This is the best solution, passing the size of the array and then the actual array.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: I should add the lengths of items into the array. Ok. But how do I call the functions with the items as arguments?

Comment: Look at the last line of the answer. That's calling f0 passing it a 1 (for the number of args) plus a pointer to the fifth position in the array. Actually, I'd probably make 'array' into an array of structs (instead of a 3D array) where each struct has 3 fields: the function, the number of args, and an array of args. Then you'd say `(array[i].f)(array[i].n, array[i].args)` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you just want:

```
array[i][0](array[i][1]);
```

To call a function from its pointer in C only requires the function call operator, which is parentheses.

Possibly useful link:  http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Comment: That's interesting. What format should be the arguments stored in? I mean, to call a function f(int a, int b) is it ok to write:
int[] a = [1, 2];
void *pointer = &f;
*pointer(a);
?
I'm totally lost....

Comment: That's a good question.  You don't use "*pointer(a)" -- the dereference is implied, so you don't need the "*", only "pointer(a)".  When a function is called this way, type-checking of arguments can't be done at compile-time.  A "typedef" shared by the functions in question would help with that.  There's more information at the link at the very end of the function pointer section, just before the section "Strings (and why there's no such thing".

Answer (score 0):

c does not have a built in notion of lists or [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension), you have to set up an explicit loop over an array, and have to support the length of the list yourself.

Yes, this is wordier than the python way, but that is because python is handling the details for you.

Data structures that are reasonably well suited to handling notional "lists":

- dynamic arrays (possibly wrapped in a [`struct`](http://www.space.unibe.ch/comp_doc/c_manual/C/SYNTAX/struct.html) to let you hold meta info like the current length and allocated length in the same place)
- [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

If you choose an array based solution you will need to either

1. keep track of the current length and pass it to the processing functions
2. use a sentinel to mark the end of the data (which might mean using a larger data type to allow you to specify a sentinel that can not appear in the data)

linked lists can be processed node by node because the have a natural end.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void f0(int a              ){ printf("f0(%i)\n",      a    ); }
void f1(int a, int b       ){ printf("f1(%i,%i)\n",   a,b  ); }
void f2(int a, int b, int c){ printf("f2(%i,%i,%i)\n",a,b,c); }

typedef void (*f_arg1)(int);
typedef void (*f_arg2)(int,int);
typedef void (*f_arg3)(int,int,int);

struct fn_call {
  f_arg1 fn;
  int arg_num;
  int *args;
} array[] = {  { (f_arg1)f0, 1, (int[]){5}               },
               { (f_arg1)f1, 2, (int[]){-23, 5}          },
               { (f_arg1)f2, 3, (int[]){0, 1, 2}         },
               { (f_arg1)f2, 3, (int[]){1235, 111, 4234} },
               { (f_arg1)f0, 1, (int[]){22}              }   };

void apply( struct fn_call *call ){
  switch( call->arg_num ){
  case 1: ((f_arg1)call->fn)( call->args[0] );                  break;
  case 2: ((f_arg2)call->fn)( call->args[0], call->args[1] );   break;
  case 3: ((f_arg3)call->fn)( call->args[0], call->args[1], call->args[2] );
  }
}

int main(){
  for(unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(array); i++)  apply( &array[i] );
}
```

Result:

```
f0(5)
f1(-23,5)
f2(0,1,2)
f2(1235,111,4234)
f0(22)
```